# NgCordova File não gera arquivo

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou usando o $cordovaFile(ngCordova) + ionic para meu aplicativo e preciso armazenar um json em um arquivo local mais não estou conseguindo gerar o arquivo para popular com o json.

controller.js

app.controller('ControllerEletrica', function($scope, $stateParams,jsonBanco,$cordovaFile) {

```
        jsonBanco.getjson().then(function (data) {
        $scope.dados = data.dados;
            console.log($scope.dados);
    });
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

$cordovaFile.createFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "new_file.txt", true)
      .then(function (success) {
       console.log('FOI');
      }, function (error) {
        console.log('NAO FOI');
      });
});

});
```